# How do decentralised apps handle logging out via walletconnect

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask, wallet-connect

After logging into https://opensea.io with metamask I see that they have a log out functionality.

After some [research](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/8990), I realized that the "log out" is just a change in UI as I'm still connected to metamask and can only disconnect if I do so manually using the metamask chrome extension.

However, after I log in to opensea using wallectconnect with my mobile phone using a wallet app like dcentwallet, I see that my app shows that I am logged in and I have an option to disconnect manually using the app. However, if I log out using opensea, I disconnect from my wallet app.

So I assume that opensea is using some kind of event to force my app to disconnect from its site. I assume it's not a web3 event because I'm not asked for my signature when I log out of opensea and it forcibly disconnects me from my wallet app. Does anyone know what technique opensea is using to disconnect mobile wallet apps connected via walletconnect?

Answer (score 1):

WalletConnect connects Clients and Servers via so called sessions. WC protocol provides a specific `disconnect` command for a Client side (OpenSea in your case). Client sends this command to the WC, WC kills the session and send a notification to the Server (a wallet app) that the session is dead.

Vice versa the wallet app may disconnect from its side, which is again basically WC killing the session and notifying the dApp/Client